# Is default language app preview used in all localizations in AppStoreConnect?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, app-preview

If I only upload app preview video for default language, will it display in other stores/languages, if there's no app preview uploaded there in AppStoreConnect?

Didn't find info in official guides, and don't want to manually upload 4x12 videos :(

Answer (score 1):

When You add a new language, by default it will take the preview video and screenshots of the `Primary Language` unless you press edit and put a localized version
[image]

Comment: The languages are already added. And have screenshots uploaded there. What happens in this case?

Comment: In this case, No, the video will not appear in this language page, you have to upload a video.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who's interested - app preview is not used, if you have localized screenshots uploaded in certain localization. If you're only localizing texts, than you add a new language and clearly see what @Jabbar posted above.

But if you have localized screenshots but app preview is uploaded only in default language - than you'll have to upload app preview to each of those localized languages as well.
Strangely, if you don't do this app preview will play in app store search screen, but **not** in the app page.

Thank you Apple for being so clear about this!